# what is the meaning of this sentence "In our previous examples we took n to be the number for which a given function is to be computed"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, relative-clauses

> In our previous examples we took n to be the number for which a
>   given function is to be computed.

I am not sure about the meaning of the above sentence because I'm confused about this part: **"for which a given function is to be computed"**

Comment: If I understand that sentence correctly, I would say, "In our previous examples we used *n* as the input number to the given functions to be computed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to paraphrase that:

> In our previous example we took ***n*** to be a number with a specific role: A given function was to be computed *for **that number***.

In this paraphrased version, the prepositional phrase "for that number" modifies the passive infinitive "to be computed".  The entire second sentence tells us the specific role which ***n*** plays.

In the original, "for which" does the same job as "for that number" does in the paraphrased version.  It also does a bit more.  This "which" makes the entire second clause subordinate and relative to the phrase "the number".  Instead of standing as a sentence on its own, the relative clause as a whole does the same job that the prepositional phrase "with a specific role" does in the paraphrased version.

Instead of two independent clauses in separate sentences, the original is a complex sentence with one independent clause and one subordinate clause.